# How to efficiently calculate distance matrix in pytorch for two sets 3D tensors with different sizes?

Tags: python, pytorch, distance

I have tensors X of shape BxCxHxW and Y of shape NxCxHxW. B is batch size, C is channels, H is height, W is width, and N will be constant for any batch. Basically I want the BxN distance matrix of distances between a set of B images and another set of N images.

I tried using torch.cdist by reshaping X as 1xBx(C*H*W) and Y as 1xNx(C*H*W) by unsqueezing a dimension and flattening the last 3 channels, but I did a sanity check and got wrong answers with this method.

I want L2 distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation page for [`torch.cdist`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cdist.html?highlight=cdist#torch.cdist), the two inputs and outputs are shaped in the following manner: `x1`: `(B, P, M)`, `x2`: `(B, R, M)`, and `output`: `(B, P, R)`.

To match your case: `B=1`, `P=B`, `R=N`, while `M=C*H*W` (*i.e.* flattened). As you just explained.

So you are basically going for:

```
>>> torch.cdist(X[None].flatten(2), Y[None].flatten(2))
```

---

If you're not convinced, you can check with the following method:

```
>>> dist = []
>>> for x in X:
...    for y in Y:
...       dist.append((x-y).norm())
```

And compare the `torch.cdist` result with `torch.tensor(dist).reshape(len(X), len(Y))`.